# Blazor: Unable to update selected dropdown, while textbox value updated

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor

When I try to update the vehicle Year and Make (Dropdownlist from another table, I manage to update it without any error. But, The value for the dropdownlist was not updated, while the value for Year is updated. Here are the 2 models:

```
public class Vehicle : BaseDomainModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Year { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int MakeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Make Make { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
    public class Make : BaseDomainModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Vehicle model have relationship with Make model (1 Vehicle = 1 Model).
When I Update the Vehicle, the Year is updated, while the dropdownvalue is not.
Here is the controller,

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutVehicle(int id, Vehicle Vehicle)
    {
        if (id != Vehicle.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _unitOfWork.Vehicles.Update(Vehicle);

        try
        {
            await _unitOfWork.Save(HttpContext);
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!await VehicleExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Here is the Razor component:

```
<EditForm Model="@vehicle" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />
<ValidationSummary />

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Make: </label>
    <div>
        <select @bind="vehicle.MakeId" class="form-control">
            <option value="">-- Select Make --</option>
            @if (Makes != null)
            {
                foreach (var make in Makes)
                {
                    <option value="@make.Id">@make.Name</option>
                }
            }
        </select>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => vehicle.MakeId)" />
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Year:</label>
    <div>
        <InputNumber @bind-Value="@vehicle.Year" class="form-control" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => vehicle.Year)" />
    </div>
</div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
    @ButtonText
</button>
<BackToList Target="vehicles" />
</EditForm>
 
@code {
private IList<Make> Makes;
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Makes = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Make>>($"{Endpoints.MakesEndpoint}");
}
[Parameter] public bool Disabled { get; set; } = false;
[Parameter] public Vehicle vehicle { get; set; }
[Parameter] public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Save";
[Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
}
```

Did I miss anything?

Code available Here:  [GITHUB LINK](https://github.com/trevoirwilliams/CarRentalManagement-Blazor-WASM/tree/2ee3d4e311fa5012b0189fa4f4d2c5907d6a224d)

Answer (score 0):

Add a string to your model

```
public string SelectedMake { get; set; } = "mymake";
```

Change your select from

```
<select @bind="vehicle.MakeId" class="form-control">
```

to

```
<select @bind="vehicle.SelectedMake" class="form-control">
```

As your using **EditForm**, to handle validation your Select should ideally be a **InputSelect**

```
<InputSelect @bind-Value="vehicle.SelectedMake" @oninput="onChangeMake" class="...." >    </InputSelect>
```

Add selected after http call

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
     await _client.GetFromJsonAsync
      
    vehicle.SelectedMake= .....;
  
}
```

Not tested, pls post a blazor fiddle, if it does not work

Comment: Still didnt work. See full code here. https://github.com/trevoirwilliams/CarRentalManagement-Blazor-WASM/tree/2ee3d4e311fa5012b0189fa4f4d2c5907d6a224d